# Functionalities such as bg and font from Tkinter package is not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on an Email Spam Classifier model and when I wanted to make a GUI, tkinter package is showing errors like

```
TclError: unknown option "-font"
TclError: unknown option "-borderwidth" 
TclError: unknown option "-bg"
TclError: unknown option "-relief"
```

It seems like none of the functionalities of the Tkinter package seems to work. I've tried a lot of methods but still no result.
Please help me.
I've attached my code below

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk


def GUI():

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry('500x200')
        root.maxsize(500,200)
        root.minsize(500,200)
        root.title('Email Spam Classifier')
        root['bg'] = "white"
        
        title = Label(root,text="Email Spam Classifier",font=('verdana',15,'bold'))
        title.place(x=180,y=5)
        
          
        
        
        
        Label(root,text="Enter mail to Classify ",font=('verdana',10,'bold')).place(x=50,y=50)
        
        url = Entry(root,width=50)
        url.place(x=50,y=80)
        
        button = Button(root,text="Predict",font=('verdana',8,'bold'))
        button.place(x=360,y=78)
        root.mainloop()
GUI()
```

Please help me with this.
I'm new to this community, so if I had done some mistake in alignment of the text or method of asking, excuse me please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because of `tkinter.ttk`. The widgets in `ttk` do not have those options.

Comment: This is a  really good illustration of why using wildcard imports is bad.

Comment: You can find some `ttk` widget-related information [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html).

Comment: This is why I now always post this advice when I see someone importing using wildcard: "I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue."

Comment: Thank you, your advise helped me and I have successfully rectified the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [wildcard import](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

The `Button` class is present in both the `tkinter` module and the `tkinter.ttk` module.
If the `tkinter.ttk` import follows the `tkinter` import, it [overrides widgets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#using-ttk) with the same class names. And vice versa.

In your code, the button is `tkinter.ttk.Button`.
The style properties for this button are [set differently](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-styling).

If you want to use `tkinter.Button`, you need to explicitly specify which button it is.

```py
button = tk.Button(root,text="Predict",font=('verdana',8,'bold'))
```

---

If you are using ttkthemes, you need to use **ttk widgets** to apply the theme to them.

```py
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk


def GUI():

        root = ThemedTk(theme="arc") # light theme
        root.geometry('630x200')
        root.maxsize(630, 200)
        root.minsize(630, 200)
        root.title('Email Spam Classifier')
        # this will work too:
        # root["background"] = "white"
        # root.config(background="white")

        style = ttk.Style()
        # font for all ttk Buttons
        style.configure("TButton", font=('verdana',8,'bold'))
        # font for all ttk Labels
        style.configure("TLabel", font=('verdana',10,'bold'))
        # font for a specific ttk Label
        style.configure("Title.TLabel", font=('verdana',15,'bold'))

        title = ttk.Label(root, text="Email Spam Classifier",
                          style="Title.TLabel")
        title.place(x=180, y=5)
        
        enter_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Enter mail to Classify ")
        enter_label.place(x=50, y=50)

        url = ttk.Entry(root, width=50)
        url.place(x=50, y=80)
        print(url.winfo_reqwidth()) # 412

        # the button has been moved because it is overlapping the entry
        button = ttk.Button(root, text="Predict")
        button.place(x=412+50, y=79)
        print(button.winfo_reqwidth())

        root.mainloop()
       
GUI()
```

Comment: Widget options - [Tcl/Tk Documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/contents.htm)